# How to include a partial in app template (symfony)

Tags: php, symfony1, partial

I have created a template `home.php` in `app/frontend/templates/home.php`

I include this template if my user isn't connected. I try to include 2 partials :

```
<?php echo get_partial('sfGuardAuth/signin_form', array('form' => $form)) ?>
<?php echo get_partial('news/listNews', array('listNews' => $listNews)) ?>
```

But when I want to use variables `$form` and `$listNews`, I have errors :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: form

Notice: Undefined variable: listNews
```

Why ?

Comment: because those variables are not set

Comment: try to set them first to a value then use them inside the function

Comment: Yes I have understand my problem. Now I use components to set the variables andit works properly. thanks

Comment: Yes, using components is the solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using components resolves the problem